# How can I reflect <role-link> as an annotation in EJB 3

Tags: annotations, ejb, ejb-3.1, ejb-2.x

I try migrate an EJB2.1 projetk into EJB3.1. I did not find any annotation for . How can i reflect this tag.

The ejb-jar.xml part looks like:

```
<security-role-ref>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
            <role-link>adm_role</role-link>
</security-role-ref>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no separate annotation, linking security role reference to security role can be done only in deployment descriptor (as in your ejb.jar.xml fragment). This is explained in details at chapter 17.3.3 in EJB 3.1 specification and there is no word about doing it via annotations.

Comment: I want to get rid of ejb-jar.xml. Which way should i follow?

Comment: As I said - you can define this only in ejb-jar.xml not with annotations, so you cannot get rid of ejb-jar.xml.